# Firebase push - deletes unique object and inserts new one (Overwrites content basically)

Tags: javascript, firebase

I have an application that is running with firebase. When I try to use the push() method, it basically overwrites the existing JSON. Here's an example:
First time around, the following JSON is generated:

---

`JSON
"deviceIDs" : {
    "-JzCx5C_13eoXPEgklMW" : {
      "author" : "gracehop22",
      "deviceID" : "99alpha",
      "title" : "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    }
  }`

---

Next time around, if I call the same function, the above JSON is deleted and a new JSON is inserted such as this one:

---

`JSON
"deviceIDs" : {
    "-JzCxbuEj2V1kmvvgqnc" : {
      "author" : "gracehop22",
      "deviceID" : "99alpha",
      "title" : "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    }
  }`

---

Here's my code snippet:

```
function CreateUserProfile(UID, name, email, deviceID) {

    var ref = new Firebase($scope.firebaseurl + '/' + UID);
    var profileArray = {UserProfile:{}};
    profileArray.UserProfile.UID = UID;
    profileArray.UserProfile.name = name;
    profileArray.UserProfile.email = email;
    profileArray.UserProfile.deviceID = deviceID;

    var onComplete = function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log('Synchronization failed');
        } else {

            //1. On Success, Store Key User Profile Elements
            localStorage.setItem("kasimaProfileInfo",JSON.stringify(profileArray));

            $rootScope.username = name;

            //2. Hide the feedback and change screens
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.HideFeedback();
                $scope.ChangeLoc('/featured');
            }, 1500);
        }
    };
    ref.set(profileArray, onComplete);


    var postsRef = ref.child("deviceIDs");
    var newPostRef = postsRef.push();
    newPostRef.set({
        deviceID: deviceID,
        author: "gracehop22",
        title: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    });
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting the entire ref when you're setting `profileArray`:

```
...
ref.set(profileArray, onComplete);

var postsRef = ref.child("deviceIDs");
...
```

You'll probably want to use `update()` there:

```
...
ref.update(profileArray, onComplete);

var postsRef = ref.child("deviceIDs");
...
```

### Update

The Firebase `update()` functions set the value of the properties in the JSON object you pass it. So your new `profileArray.UserProfile` will replace the existing data.

The solution is to not build a nested JSON structure locally, but instead update the data at the lower location where it needs updating:

```
ref.child('UserProfile').update(profileArray.UserProfile, onComplete);
```

This removes the entire need for the `profileArray`:

```
var userProfile = {
  UID: UID,
  name: name,
  email: email,
  decideID: deviceID
};
ref.child('UserProfile').update(userProfile, onComplete);
```

For a working example, see: http://jsbin.com/ciqoge/edit?js,console

*For a next time: if you provide such a jsbin/jsfiddle straight away, it will be much easier to quickly help you.*

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for getting back to me on this. My problem mainly is with the "push()". I tried switching the ref.set to ref.update but it still removes my previous unique key and inserts a new one. 

The push that is right after the "ref.set" statement ==> 

var postsRef = ref.child("deviceIDs");
    var newPostRef = postsRef.push();
    newPostRef.set({
        deviceID: deviceID,
        author: "gracehop22",
        title: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
    });
<==== it keeps on removing my original unique key and re-adding a new one. Instead of adding a new one.

Comment: I am basically trying to maintain a list of deviceIDs for a particular user. A user can login using his tablet or phone. So when a user login with their tablet, I update the UserProfile info with the ref.set and insert the deviceID into the array of "deviceIDs". Then when a user login from his phone I update the UserProfile info with ref.set or ref.update and insert / push the new device ID into the array. Thanks again !

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot.